# shell script (e.g. sed) to create mapping with character replacements

Tags: shell, sed

I have a variable in bash holding a string `"<topic>...<topic>"`representing topics that need to be mapped into a database table name, replacing illegal characters, via a mapping configuration:

The required mapping format is `"topic1:table1,topic2:table2"` – that is, this is the output I need.

For context, this is a configuration entry for [Snowflake Kafka Connector](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/kafka-connector) which helps streaming data from a topic into a table, and importantly, table names are much more restricted in the characters allowed.

In this most simple case, the illegal character is a hyphen which should be converted to an underscore.

For example, for `"foo-bar,boo-baz"` as the input string, the required answer would be:

`"foo-bar:foo_bar,boo-baz:boo_baz"`.

In Python, this is straight-forward:

```py
import sys
s = sys.argv[1]
print(','.join(p + ':' + p.replace('-', '_') for p in s.split(',')))
```

I'm looking for a solution based on shell scripting tools to avoid installing additional software.

I know that sed for example [has labels](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Branching-and-flow-control.html) which I think can help with this, but I haven't been able to work out a solution.

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: @Cyrus good point – I have been looking at sed's label and not really been able to work out anything. I added a Python solution which is what I'm using right now, but ideally I would be able to solve this without adding additional tools to the mix (trying to keep a container image within a reasonable size).

Comment: Shells, and many shell tools (e.g. `grep`) do not handle binary data well. Other languages, e.g. `perl` has features that make binary data handling easy. Start with `man perl`, and there's a book "Programming Perl".

Comment: @waltinator I agree, but this has nothing to do with binary ...

Comment: @malthe show us an example. Is the string in question within a file or a database? Is it a single string or multiple lines? ..

Comment: @ValentinBajrami just a single string, held in a bash variable. I have updated the question to reflect this a little better. Thanks

Comment: Does it also need to include mapping for topics that don't include the character you want to replace?

Comment: @aviro I believe so and presumably it makes the solution more straight-forward too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the input in a variable called `TOPICS`:

#### Using `sed`:

```
sed 's/[^,]\+/\0:\0/g; :a s/:\([^-,]\+\)-/:\1_/g; ta' <<<"$TOPICS"
```

1. `s/[^,]\+/\0:\0/g` - Take each topic (a word that doesn't contain a comma), and add the same word after it with a colon. The result after this part would be: `foo-bar:foo-bar,boo-baz:boo-baz`
2. `:a s/:\([^-,]\+\)-/:\1_/g` - replace the hyphen after every colon with underscore.

- At this point it would only replace the first hyphen within each topic, so for instance if one of the topics is `foo-bar-baz`, and after the first step with have `foo-bar-baz:foo-bar-baz`, after this step the result would be `foo-bar-baz:foo_bar-baz`.

3. `ta` - if the latest substitution was successful (a hyphen was replaced with an underscore) - go back to the `:a` label to check if there are more substitutions to be made. This is in case there's a topic that has more than one hyphen. If no substitution was made in step 2, don't branch back to the label - continue to the next line.

- For instance: `foo-bar-baz:foo_bar-baz` from the previous example will now become `foo-bar-baz:foo_bar_baz`.

#### Using `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN {ORS=RS=","} { if (gsub( /\n$/, "" )) ORS="\n"; NEW=$0; gsub("-", "_", NEW); print $0":"NEW}' <<<"$TOPICS"
```

1. `RS` (Input Record Separator) and `ORS` (Output Record Separator) are set to `,`. That way `awk` will treat every topic as a separate line.
2. `if (gsub( /\n$/, "" )) ORS="\n"` - If the last character of the word is `\n` (a new line), remove it. `gsub` will return the number of replacements (1), and then on the last word it will not print the new line after the read word, but only as the last (Output Record Separator).
3. `gsub("-", "_", NEW)` - replace hyphens with underscores.

#### Using `awk` + `sed` + `tr`:

We have additional commands here, but it might be a bit easier to read:

```
echo "$TOPICS" \
 | tr ',' '\n' \
 | awk '{NEW=$0; gsub("-", "_", NEW); print $0":"NEW}' \
 | tr '\n' ',' \
 | sed 's/,$/\n/'
```

1. `tr ',' '\n'` - First separate the words with a new line.
2. `awk` to print the mapping.
3. `tr '\n' ','` - Replace newlines back with commas.
4. `sed 's/,$/\n/'` - Except for the last comma, which should be replaced with a newline.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to manipulate the string only, one way of achieving this would be as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

p="foo-bar,boo-baz"
IFS=',' read -ra arr <<< "$p"
result=()

for item in "${arr[@]}"; do
  result+=("${item}:${item//-/_}")
done

end_result=$(printf '%s,' "${result[@]}")
echo "${end_result%,*}"
```

If you want to know about string manipulation , see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100

Comment: Nitpick (I can't make such a small edit), the two colons appearing in the last two lines should be commas.

Comment: @malthe does the above not satisfy your requirement? It is a variable which holds just that string and then some string manipulation. Is there anything not covered in the snippet?

Comment: I think this is a good answer and it certainly satisfies the requirement. It's a little verbose though and I was kind of fishing for an answer that's essentially a one-liner.

Comment: Yes, the mapping are supposed to be separated by commas. The colons represent the mapping themselves. In your case you're using colons for both the mapping and the separation. Your result should be `foo-bar:foo_bar,boo-baz:boo_baz` and not `foo-bar:foo_bar:boo-baz:boo_baz`.

Comment: Oh that is sharp aviro. I will update the answer later on today as I don't have access to a compurer right now. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ echo 'foo-bar,boo-baz' |
    awk -F',' '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {t=$i; gsub(/-/,"_",t); printf "%s:%s%s", $i, t, (i<NF ? FS : ORS)}}'
foo-bar:foo_bar,boo-baz:boo_baz
```

or if you prefer:

```
$ echo 'foo-bar,boo-baz' |
    awk -v RS=',' '{t=$1; gsub(/-/,"_",t); printf "%s:%s%s", $1, t, (sub(/\n$/,"") ? ORS : RS)}'
foo-bar:foo_bar,boo-baz:boo_baz
```

The second one will fail if the input doesn't end in a newline (which it should to be a valid text file per POSIX).